# Timeline using charts in exel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

what I'm trying to do is, visualize dates on the x-axis of a chart.
Somehow it is not working as expected.

e.g. I have three dates:

```
one     05.05.2017
two     08.08.2017
three   02.02.2017
```

which I want to display as milestones.

Its working perfectly fine if I use a `barchart`:
[image]

But insted of the bars I want just have markers. e.g. like this:
[image]

I tried using a `line chart with markers`, but I'm not able to get the x-axis to hold dates.

Any ideas how to solve this? (I know diagrams are more likely to be used for other stuff, but it drives me crazy that its working perfectly on bar charts but not on line charts)

Comment: You could try a x-y-diagram. This should get your wanted result.

Comment: The x-y chart should do the trick. Just don't forget to change the Axis type in the Format Axis -> Axis Options -> Axis Type to Text Axis to display correctly the date in the X axis.